# Add alpha channel to an .exr file in python

Tags: python, opencv, openexr

I'm trying to add an alpha channel to an .exr file(RGB) using OpenEXR python library or OpenCV, couldn't figure out how. Here's where I am.

```
import OpenEXR,Imath,array,os
import numpy as np

def write_exr_alpha(dir,output_dir):
    z_file = OpenEXR.InputFile(dir)
    FLOAT = Imath.PixelType(Imath.PixelType.FLOAT)
    (z,_,_) = [array.array('f', z_file.channel(Chan, FLOAT)).tolist() for Chan in ("R", "G", "B") ]
    dw = z_file.header()['dataWindow']
    sz = (dw.max.x - dw.min.x + 1, dw.max.y - dw.min.y + 1)
    os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(output_dir), exist_ok=True)
    #get alpha values
    As = np.ones(np.array(z).shape)
    pos = np.where(np.array(z) > 100)[0]
    As[pos] = 0
    zs = array.array('f',z).tobytes()
    out = OpenEXR.OutputFile(output_dir, OpenEXR.Header(sz[0], sz[1]))
    # write to .exr with alpha channel
    out.writePixels({'R' : zs, 'G' : zs, 'B' : zs ,'A': As})
```

and OpenCV

```
import os,cv2
import numpy as np

def write_exr_alpha(dir,output_dir):
    os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(output_dir), exist_ok=True)
    image=cv2.imread(dir,cv2.IMREAD_ANYCOLOR | cv2.IMREAD_ANYDEPTH)
    normal_b, normal_g, normal_r = cv2.split(image)
    As = np.ones(normal_b.shape, dtype=normal_b.dtype)
    pos = np.where(np.array(image[:,:,0]) > 100)
    for i in range(0,len(pos)):
        As[pos[0][i]][pos[1][i]]=0
    image_out = cv2.merge((normal_r, normal_g, normal_b, As))
    cv2.imwrite(output_dir,image_out)
```

Edit: A test [sample](https://drive.google.com/file/d/16NybPR3xeVCHKwymyYUbKf-oB45zrY4Q/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: please check `cv2.getBuildInformation()` to see, if your cv2 actually *has* exr support builtin (which is rather unlikely)  also: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/16115

Comment: Did you get an error? Was any file created at all, or nothing? Did you check the shape and `dtype` of all your Numpy arrays? Did you run the debugger?

Comment: @MarkSetchell I didn't get any error, there were .exr files written for both methods using the code posted but neither has alpha channel. All shape match and dtype are all float32.

Comment: @berak The issue was completed according to that thread, that's why I tried using OpenCV.

Comment: Please share a link to a sample image that exhibits this problem. Thank you.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Added sample https://drive.google.com/file/d/16NybPR3xeVCHKwymyYUbKf-oB45zrY4Q/view?usp=sharing

Comment: That image works fine with OpenCV for me. Try making your code really, really simple. Load the image, convert to RGBA `result = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2BGRA)`, save in current directory under new name, check result with `exiftool`

Comment: @MarkSetchell If you load and convert to RGBA then save it to .exr then read it in Photoshop or Blender to check, the new .exr still doesn't have any alpha information.